# Fibonnacci recursive call

Tags: java, recursion, trace

How many times is the fib method in  invoked for fib(6).
where the fib method is

```
public static long fib(long index) {
    if (index == 0) // Base case
      return 0;
    else if (index == 1) // Base case
      return 1;
   else // Reduction and recursive calls
     return fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);
      }
}
```

I end up tracing the recursive call to find how many times this method was called but this is so unpractical. Does this have a closed form function where you replace the value tested to know how many recursive call you will get?

Note that this was a question in my previous exam, (Exam is written) I know I could have used a count variable. Sorry for not mentioning this in the first place. This why am asking if there is a close form function for it.

Comment: How about incrementing a counter every time it's called, and printing it at the end?

Comment: You should try to solve the recurrence equation

Comment: add counter which you can increment after calling this method and at the end you can print count value.

Comment: Might be of some help  - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178375/what-will-the-recursion-tree-of-fibonacci-series-look-like

Comment: Case base: `0` and `1` it returns 1, the no base case: calls(n) = 1 + calls(n -1)  + calls(n -2). so: `calls(fib(0)): 1,
calls(fib(1)): 1,
calls(fib(2)): 3,
calls(fib(3)): 5,
calls(fib(4)): 9,
calls(fib(5)): 15,
calls(fib(6)): 25`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass some kind of Counter as an additional parameter that gets increased every time the function gets called:

```
class Counter {
    private int value = 0;
    public void increment() {
      value++;
    }

    public int getCurrentValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

So that your code will become:

```
public static long fib(long index, Counter counter) {
   counter.increment();
   if (index == 0) // Base case
       return 0;
   else if (index == 1) // Base case
       return 1;
   else // Reduction and recursive calls
      return fib(index - 1, counter) + fib(index - 2, counter);
   }
}
```

The invocation:

```
Counter counter = new Counter();
fib(6,counter);
counter.getCurrentValue(); //  retrieve the current value which is exactly the number of invocation of fib function
```

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to add a static counter to your containing class:

```
public class YourFib {
    private static int counter;

    public static long fib(long index) {
        ++counter;
        if (index == 0) // Base case
            return 0;
        else if (index == 1) // Base case
            return 1;
        else // Reduction and recursive calls
            return fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        counter = 0;
        fib(6l);
        System.out.println("There were " + counter + " recursive calls.");
    }
}
```

By the way, computing the Fibonacci sequence using recursion is seriously sub-optimal.  You should read about the dynamic programming say of doing this, where each level only needs to be computed once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
public class A {
    private static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println(fib(6));
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    public static long fib(long index) {
        count++;
        if (index == 0) // Base case
            return 0;
        else if (index == 1) // Base case
            return 1;
        else // Reduction and recursive calls
            return fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a integer variable in your main function, `public static int count = 0;`. Then but this variable into your recursive function shown as below:

```
`public static long fib(long index) {
     count ++;
     if (index == 0) // Base case
       return 0;
     else if (index == 1) // Base case
       return 1;
      else // Reduction and recursive calls
       return fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);}`
```